# OPC-UA whats the difference between "Value" and "Attribute Value"

Tags: c#, server, iot, opc-ua

I am actually learning OPC-UA. I am using the c# demo server of LibUA (can be freely downloaded here: https://github.com/nauful/LibUA). For each node there, I am seeing two values, one which is constantly changing in the "Data Access View" and one which is static in the "Attributes" view:

[image]

After having a look at the code and reading about how subscriptions work in OPC-UA i understand now why the dynamic value is constantly changing. But what is about this "static" value in the attribute window? Whats the reason for this? Why do we have two values per node, one dynamic and one static?

The static one is generated by a method called "HandleReadRequestInternal" in the demo server. Whats a "internal" read request? I couldn't find anything about this in the specs. Maybe some expert can help me here to bring some clarity. :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here we are dealing with two different views in the OPC UA client tool:

### **1. Dynamic value in the Data Access View**

The dynamic value that you see in the Data Access View is the latest value of the node received from the server at the configured publishing interval. This is related to subscriptions for data change notification in OPC UA which is used to reduce the overhead of continuously polling from the client side for the value of a node in the server.

- OPC UA Client can subscribe to Variable Nodes in the Server to reduce overheads
- OPC UA Server will monitor the value of those Variable Nodes at a configurable sampling interval
- OPC UA Server will notify the Client of data change at a configurable publishing interval
- OPC UA Client updates the value of the Variable node in the Data Access View each time its value changes in the data change notification received from the Server

### **2. Static value in the Attribute View**

The static value which you see in the Attribute View is the value of the Variable Node that is fetched by the Client from the Server each time you click on the Node or each time you click on the refresh button in the Attribute View. This is done through the OPC UA read service that you can use to read Attributes of a Node (Value Attribute in this case). An example is shown in this screenshot of a sample Wireshark trace pasted here – you can see a ReadRequest packet that an OPC UA Client is sending to a Server to read the Value Attribute of a Node with NodeId 2258.

[image]

I see that you are learning OPC UA and using open source implementations. Here are some other open source implementations that you might be interested in trying out:

- open62541 – https://open62541.org/certified-sdk.html – C stack | Mozilla License | Embedded ready | TSN ready
- NodeOPCUA – https://node-opcua.github.io/ – NodeJS | MIT License | Cloud ready
- FreeOpcUa – https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua – C++ | LGPL-3.0 License | Python bindings
- UA .NET stack – https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard – RCL License for corporate members of OPC Foundation & GPL 2.0 for others | Standard profile | Web oriented implementation

If you are looking for more hands-on information, you can also check out these resources:

- Free documentation: You can look at the open source documentation page: https://open62541.org/doc/current/
- Paid online course: Practical introduction to OPC UA – code walk-through and examples in this course use the open62541 stack: https://opcfoundation.org/products/view/practical-introduction-to-opc-ua-part-i

Answer (score 1):

Value is one of the attributes that can be read from a Node, others are BrowseName, DisplayName, DataType, ValueRank etc.

The list on the right shows the attributes of the node that is clicked in the node tree that are read only once when clicked and that is independent of the subscription therefore it is not updated periodically.